# What is the correct way to instantiate c++11 random facilities

Tags: c++, c++11, random, instantiation

After looking a various examples on the uses of the new 'random' facilities in C++, I'm left a little confused as to best practices - specifically related to lifetimes of various instances.

For instance in some examples the use of "random_device" is either static in a local scope like a function, or is a static global variable or is just plainly a local.

```
--- TU ---

static std::random_device global_source;


void foo()
{
   static std::random_device local_static_source;
   static std::mt19937 gen(local_static_source());
   std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(0,10);
   ...
   dist(gen);
   ...
}

void boo()
{
   std::mt19937 gen(global_source());
   std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(0,10);
   ...
   dist(gen);
   ...
}

void roo()
{
   std::random_device local_source;
   std::mt19937 gen(local_source());
   std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(0,10);
   ...
   dist(gen);
   ...
}

int main()
{
   static std::mt19937 gen(global_source());
   std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(0,10);
   ...
   dist(gen);
   ...
  return 0;
}

--- TU ---
```

**Q1:** If "foo" or "boo" can be accessed by multiple threads, is it ok to have the generator and source be static? - is there any kind of thread safety guarantees like those in shared_ptr?

**Q2:** Is there any wording in the standard that discusses assumptions and issues related to instantiation?

Comment: There are exactly the same thread safety guarantees as for `shared_ptr`: distinct objects are independent and can be freely accessed or modified concurrently; access to the same object must be properly synchronized. Neither `foo` nor `boo` are thread-safe (though it's OK for one thread to call `foo` while another calls `boo`). The standard provides general library-wide thread safety guarantees in 17.6.5.9; there's nothing specifically for random number generators.

Comment: Correction: `foo` and `boo` are not thread-safe assuming they actually call `dist(gen)` somewhere in the code hidden by ellipsis. As written, they are safe as they don't actually do anything.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik My apologies, I was under the assumption that it was clearly self evident, that the ellipsises would imply usage of the types - I've updated the question.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Consider expanding your comments into an answer so Gerdiner can close this question as "answered".

Answer (score 1):

Some background: the reasons for allowing multiple instances of random number generators are mainly thread safety (not burdening random number generator implementations with thread synchronization) and repeatability (allowing a sequence of numbers to be repeated using the same seed).

- The former is pretty self-explanatory - there are valid cases for using RNGs in performance-critical code. With multiple instances possible, there is no expensive mutex required and random numbers can be generated on multiple CPU cores in parallel.
- The latter is generally useful when generating data sets by random. As a common example, video games may recreate the same (random) game world by driving all decisions related to the creation of the game world from the same RNG (possibly even on different networked PCs).

So the best scope for a C++ RNG depends on what you're writing:

**If you're writing a library** that might be used in the context of the above to scenarios, it is probably a good idea to let the caller provide the RNG to the individual methods or classes:

```
// Can be used on multiple CPU cores in parallel or with seed values
template <typename TRandomNumberEngine>
Point2 GetRandomPointInRectangle(
  const Rectangle2 &rect, TRandomNumberEngine &random
) {
  std::uniform_real_distribution<float> horizontal(rect.Min.X, rect.Max.X);
  float x = horizontal(random);

  std::uniform_real_distribution<float> vertical(rect.Min.Y, rect.Max.Y);
  float y = vertical(random);

  return Point2(x, y);
}
```

**If you're writing an application** or a library that uses the RNG in a supporing role (eg. geometric fitting algorithms), ie. you're just interested in non-repeatable random numbers, the best scope for a random number generator would be the largest possible scope that doesn't introduce unwanted coupling between modules.

That could be a simple private object variable in whatever class needs random numbers or even a `thread_local` singleton providing the RNG of your choice if it has a lot of short-lived consumers that justify such complexity.

---

The distributions (like `std::uniform_real_distribution`) can be as short-lived as you want. They're plain functors where the constructor either has no arguments or only stores the arguments for when the functor gets executed.